# Adding a new column and using CASE while joining two tables

Tags: sql

What I am trying to do is create a new column in a table named `RecipeIngredientCheck` (which contains the following columns:`[RecipeName], [RecipeIngredientName], [Unit], [Amount], [DisplayOrder], [IngredientGroup],[VirtualProductName]`) that has to be filled according to the conditions below. However, I also need to join another table called `vw_Recipe_All` on RecipeIngredientCheck.VirtualProductName, respectively vw_Recipe_All.Name, in order to get access to columns such as `[RecipeIngredientUnitId], [g], [teaspoon]` etc.

`vw_Recipe_All` list of columns:

```
[RecipeIsVerified],[IngredientGroup],[IngredientId],[IngredientDisplayName],[IngredientAmount] ,[IngredientUnit],[RecipeLine] ,[VirtualProductName] ,[Id] ,[IsVerified],[Name],[PricePerStandardUnit],[NativeUnitId] ,[Kg] ,[g],[l] ,[dl] ,[unit] ,[empty],[pack],[teaspoon],[spoon],[can] ,[bundle],[clove] ,[smidgen],[cube],[stick]  ,[slice]     ,[letter],[Glass] ,[RecipeIngredientUnitId]
```

The below conditions are made specifically for the table vw_Reciple_All but as I stated above, I am trying to create a new column in another table.

```
select RecipeId,RecipeName,Name,IngredientAmount,IngredientDisplayName,IngredientUnit,
CASE 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=1 THEN g / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=2 THEN teaspoon / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=3 THEN spoon / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=4 THEN smidgen / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=6 THEN l / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=7 THEN dl / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=9 THEN unit / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=10 THEN bundle / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=11 THEN stick / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=12 THEN kg / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=13 THEN unit / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=14 THEN clove / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=15 THEN can / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=16 THEN slice / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=17 THEN [cube] / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=18 THEN glass / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=19 THEN pack / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=20 THEN letter / (CASE WHEN NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(unit,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
    END as AmountInStandardUnit
from vw_Recipe_All
```

I was thinking of something like this, but I am getting a lot of NULL values instead.

```
UPDATE RecipeIngredientChecking
SET AmountInStandardUnit =
    CASE 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=1 THEN g / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=2 THEN teaspoon / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=3 THEN spoon / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=4 THEN smidgen / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=6 THEN l / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=7 THEN dl / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=9 THEN vw_Recipe_All.unit / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=10 THEN bundle / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=11 THEN stick / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=12 THEN kg / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=13 THEN vw_Recipe_All.unit / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=14 THEN clove / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=15 THEN can / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=16 THEN slice / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=17 THEN [cube] / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=18 THEN glass / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=19 THEN pack / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        WHEN RecipeIngredientUnitId=20 THEN letter / (CASE WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=1 THEN COALESCE(vw_Recipe_All.unit,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=2 THEN COALESCE(l,1) WHEN vw_Recipe_All.NativeUnitId=3 THEN COALESCE(kg,1) END) * IngredientAmount 
        END
from RecipeIngredientChecking Inner Join vw_Recipe_All ON RecipeIngredientChecking.VirtualProductName=vw_Recipe_All.Name
```

Does anyone have a better idea of how can I get this to work properly? At the moment a lot of rows have NULL values in the [AmountInStandardUnit] and [VirtualProductName] columns.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify the problem. (Take a look at [mcve].)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am aware of the MRE, however, I can't see what else should I exactly add in order to make it more clear?

Comment: It's more about removing stuff not needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first query works OK then just join it and `RecipeIngredientChecking` table.

```
UPDATE rci
SET AmountInStandardUnit = va.AmountInStandardUnit
FROM RecipeIngredientChecking rci
JOIN 
(
 -- your first query here
) va ON rci.VirtualProductName = va.Name
```